# Incorrect Vlookup Output VBA

Tags: vba, loops, vlookup

I have the below snippet of code:

```
For i = 2 To n
    Postcode = Cells(i, 3)

    Cells(i, "M") = Postcode

    On Error Resume Next
    EndFrameOutput = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Postcode, Dealerws3.Range("C3:D" & LastRowDealer), 2, False)
    On Error GoTo 0

    Cells(i, 4) = EndFrameOutput
Next
```

The resulting output seems to fill the cells where there should be an N/A, with the previous successfully looked up value.

Eg:
if i have this look up table:

```
Postcode    |   x
------------+-------
AB12 3BJ    |   1
IV1 1RY     |   2
```

And this Search Array:

```
Postcode
----------
AB12 3BJ
BE49 3GK
CG89 6KL
IV1 1RY
ML47 1KK
```

using my code, returning column 2 I get...

```
Postcode    |   Looked up Value
------------+-------------------
AB12 3BJ    |   1
BE49 3GK    |   1
CG89 6KL    |   1
IV1 1RY     |   2
ML47 1KK    |   2
```

instead of

```
Postcode    |   Looked up Value
------------+--------------------
AB12 3BJ    |   1
BE49 3GK    |   n/a
CG89 6KL    |   n/a
IV1 1RY     |   2
ML47 1KK    |   n/a
```

How can I adapt my code?

Comment: I would take out the on error to start with and see if it does give you any errors. And then see if the `i` does not change if that is the problem. Just change your code to include the worksheetfunction `onerror` If this is the problem I will write an answer with it all in code and all

Comment: Could you not simply use a `VLOOKUP` than complicating with VBA?

Comment: Hi Sam, the i changes. the cells(i, "m") = Postcode  code outputs the correctly looped values of Postcode....

Comment: Hi Francis, thats not an option I'm afraid.

Comment: Sam, would you mind writing your suggestion out in full code? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `Application.VLookup` instead of `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup`.  The latter throws an application error when the query is not found.  The former returns the error as the result which you can then deal with.  Since you just want the `#N/A` as the output, you don't have to do anything special with it.

And get rid of those `On Error` calls.  You won't need them with the different function, but in general you should avoid using them.

```
For i = 2 To n
    Postcode = Cells(i, 3)

    Cells(i, "M") = Postcode

    EndFrameOutput = Application.VLookup(Postcode, Dealerws3.Range("C3:D" & LastRowDealer), 2, False)

    Cells(i, 4) = EndFrameOutput
Next
```

Here is a good reference on the difference between those functions.  http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/09/24/the-worksheetfunction-method/

Comment: Hi Byron, thanks for the help. It was actually something a lot more simple. I hadn't put a line to reset the value of EndFrameOutput at the start of the loop.....school boy error.

Comment: If you use the other form of that function, you won't need to do the reset or have any of the error handling.